# Inverse of matrix sum

Tags: matrices, determinant

I found on the Wikipedia page "Determinant" the following property: 
For any invertible $m \times m$ matrix $X$, $\det(X + AB) = \det(X) \det(I_m + BX^{-1}A)$.

Is this true? If so, how is this proved?

Answer (score 0):

Two properties you can use to get there:
$$det(AB)=det(A)det(B)$$
$$det(AB)=det(BA)$$

Answer (score 0):

To prove equality
$$ \det(X+AB)=\det(X)\det(I+BX^{-1}A), \tag1$$
for any invertible matrix $X$ and arbitrary matrices $A, B$, one needs, beside the well
known equality
$$\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)=\det(BA), \tag2$$ 
also the [Sylvester's determinant theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_theorem) which says that
$$\det(I+AB)=\det(I+BA). \tag3$$
With (2) and (3) the proof of (1) is easy:
$$\det(X+AB)=\det(X)\det(I+X^{-1}AB)=\det(X)\det(I+BX^{-1}A). $$

Note that (1) can be proved without the Sylvester's determinant theorem if $A$ or $B$ is
invertible. For instance, if $A$ is invertible, then
$$ \det(X+AB)=\det(A)\det(A^{-1}X+B)=\det(A)\det(A^{-1}+BX^{-1})\det(X)= $$
$$=\det(X)\det(A^{-1}+BX^{-1})\det(A)=\det(X)\det(I+BX^{-1}A). $$